# Растянуть BottomNavigationView на всю ширину

Tags: android

В `xml` разметку добавил `BottomNavigationView`, но почему-то он обрезан по бокам и текст не отображается.

Как сделать, чтобы он был растянут на всю ширину и можно ли уменьшить размер текста, чтобы текс и иконки всегда отображались?

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что `BottomNavigationView` не достает до краев, не могу понять почему.

Comment: во-первых прикрепите разметку которая у вас вызывает проблемы, во-вторых прикрепите скриншот того что вас не устраивает, так сложно сказать в чём именно проблема, имея ту информацию что вы представили - match_parent должен помочь в параметрах виджета

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос. Почему-то по краям не достает когда добавляю 4-ый элемент меню. Если три элемента то нормально.

Comment: если вы добавите ещё один элемент в меню, то виджет дотянется до краев экрана, но это так себе решение, второй вариант - изменить корневой макет на constraint и привязать к краям виджет, у меня была такая же проблема, но была возможность добавления ещё одного пункта меню

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще довольно странно поведение у вас я так вижу, потому что я вот попробовал вашу разметку у себя в коде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по логике у вас должно быть приблизительно такое же поведение. Посмотрите на версии библиотек, может у вас старые библиотеки. [Здесь вот](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#bottom-navigation-bar) есть документация по дизайну. Библиотеки такие:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

### UPDATE

Ещё по поводу работы с пунктами меню, иконками и размером подписей. Чтобы подписи всегда отображались (я так думаю что вы это имели ввиду) нужно добавить параметр в xml виджета менюшки:

```
 app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

чтобы можно сетить свои размеры, делаем два стиля:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomNavigationView.Active" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
        <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    </style>
```

и подключаем к виджету:

```
app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Потому что constraint  тоже не помог мне.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока попробую разобраться с тем почему обрезается. Библиотеки тоже обновил, пока не пойму в чем причина.

Comment: app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" Если этот параметр добавил, то растягивается на всю ширину. Странно почему до этого не срабатывало.

Comment: Попробую еще покопаться. На устройствах с диагональю 7 и выше все равно не достает до краев.

Comment: весьма сложная ситуация)) я только что поменял устройство на 7 и у меня всё работает, как вариант - попробуйте красить сам виджет в цвет фона его элементов,  android:background="color" тогда визуально всё будет по логике нормально

Comment: Хм.. У меня же стоял параметр app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite" он то и видимо запутал меня. Это же если не ошибаюсь фон самих элементов, а не самого BottomNavigationView. поменял его на атрибут android:background="@color/colorAccent"

Comment: там где стоит item это для пунктов меню а то что просто фон это для контейнера этих пунктов меню)

Comment: да. Спасибо за помощь)